# Javascript regex for foreign names

Tags: javascript, regex, naming

I made a simple regex to validate names, the thing i hadn't thought it's that some of the users have two (or more names which is uncommon) and they have accents like áéióú.

I'm also considering other characters like the Spanish ñ or ç.

So far this is my validation code:

```
function validateForm(element) {
    var regex =  /^[a-zA-Z\-]+$/;
         var ctrl =  document.getElementById(element).value;

        if(ctrl == null || ctrl == '')
            return;

         if (!regex.test(ctrl)) {

         alert(element + ' not valid');
         document.getElementById(element).focus();
}
```

I have no idea on how to do this, any hints?

Comment: `/^.+$/` is the only safe regex for validating names.

Comment: This is a business question, not a programming question. *You* need to define your rules, and then apply them

Comment: @Amit and then throw them away, because they're almost certainly wrong - http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: Extending a bit on Niet's comment, there's no global rule for what a name must look like (therefore no useful regular expression for it), and even if there was one it would be very unlinkely that your app could benefit from checking it.

Comment: @Alnitak - that's generally true (and a great link), but some business rules do make sense and should be put in place, for example, publicly visible names (such as Alnitak) should probably be prevented from containing offensive words.

Comment: @Amit and then you fall foul of the name version of the Scunthorpe Problem

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol or maybe just exclude non-characters like number and symbols?

Comment: @Alnitak I can tell you from my own personal (and unfortunate) experience that google (gmail...) refused accepting my family name as part of my username due to a "Scunthorpe" problem. These kind of business rules are being enforced all over the place.

Comment: @Amit and like I said, should be thrown away ;-)

Comment: People can have symbols in their names.

Comment: @Alnitak I didn't see you post that link, which I reference heavily for these things.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not going to quote the entirety of [*Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names*](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/), but suffice to say a simple regex cannot accurately capture the complexity of human names.

For every rule you come up with there are guaranteed to be hundreds of exceptions. Whether its "names can't have spaces" <sup>except "van Buren"</sup>, names only have letters <sup>except O'Reily</sup>, names only have one capital letter<sup>except "McDonnell"</sup>, and so on, or even a person will have a first and last name <sup>except "Cher", "Prince", "Bono", etc...</sup>.

As said in the first comment, the only possible regex for a name is:

```
/^.+$/
```

And event that is troublesome, as it implies a name even has a written form to begin with.

---

For posterity, I'll include the list of falsehoods from the article here:

> ### Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names
>
> 1. People have exactly one canonical full name.
> 2. People have exactly one full name which they go by.
> 3. People have, at this point in time, exactly one canonical full name.
> 4. People have, at this point in time, one full name which they go by.
> 5. People have exactly N names, for any value of N.
> 6. People’s names fit within a certain defined amount of space.
> 7. People’s names do not change.
> 8. People’s names change, but only at a certain enumerated set of events.
> 9. People’s names are written in ASCII.
> 10. People’s names are written in any single character set.
> 11. People’s names are all mapped in Unicode code points.
> 12. People’s names are case sensitive.
> 13. People’s names are case insensitive.
> 14. People’s names sometimes have prefixes or suffixes, but you can safely ignore those.
> 15. People’s names do not contain numbers.
> 16. People’s names are not written in ALL CAPS.
> 17. People’s names are not written in all lower case letters.
> 18. People’s names have an order to them.  Picking any ordering scheme will automatically result in consistent ordering among all systems, as long as both use the same ordering scheme for the same name.
> 19. People’s first names and last names are, by necessity, different.
> 20. People have last names, family names, or anything else which is shared by folks recognized as their relatives.
> 21. People’s names are globally unique.
> 22. People’s names are almost globally unique.
> 23. Alright alright but surely people’s names are diverse enough such that no million people share the same name.
> 24. My system will never have to deal with names from China.
> 25. Or Japan.
> 26. Or Korea.
> 27. Or Ireland, the United Kingdom, the United States, Spain, Mexico, Brazil, Peru, Russia, Sweden, Botswana, South Africa, Trinidad, Haiti, France, or the Klingon Empire, all of which have “weird” naming schemes in common use.
> 28. That Klingon Empire thing was a joke, right?
> 29. Confound your cultural relativism!  People in my society, at least, agree on one commonly accepted standard for names.
> 30. There exists an algorithm which transforms names and can be reversed losslessly.  (Yes, yes, you can do it if your algorithm returns the input.  You get a gold star.)
> 31. I can safely assume that this dictionary of bad words contains no people’s names in it.
> 32. People’s names are assigned at birth.
> 33. OK, maybe not at birth, but at least pretty close to birth.
> 34. Alright, alright, within a year or so of birth.
> 35. Five years?
> 36. You’re kidding me, right?
> 37. Two different systems containing data about the same person will use the same name for that person.
> 38. Two different data entry operators, given a person’s name, will by necessity enter bitwise equivalent strings on any single system, if the system is well-designed.
> 39. People whose names break my system are weird outliers.  They should have had solid, acceptable names, like 田中太郎.
> 40. People have names.

Comment: Well my approach violates half of these ... ^.+$ it is from now on.

Comment: @SimonMerrick The list is informative more than operational, sometimes you do need to put a line in the sand and say "my system will only allow a person to have one name".

Comment: It depends on the domain of the problem, I understand. It just highlights that many of my previous assumptions don't necessarily hold true.

Comment: "*40. People have names.*" is my favourite... I'd like to meet `null` some day!

Comment: @Mariano Hospital systems are stacked with many "John Doe", "Jane Doe", and "Baby Smith"'s because the systems can't handle when a person doesn't have a name associated.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr Excellent example, showing a practical case where a programmer just didn't think about it (and great post btw)

Answer (score 5):

Names are bloody difficult to validate because they vary massively. As you pointed out names can be hyphened, space separated or contain scripts that most English names don't have, making accounting for all the possibilities nearly impossible.

**That being said...**

<strike>There are some simple facts that hold true for any name, foreign or otherwise, and we can test for those conditions.</strike>

**Here are some things you may or may not want to exclude.**

- Names that are empty
- Names that contain numbers
- Names that contain nonsensical characters (numbers, + _ ! @ # $ % ^ & * etc)
- Names that begin or end with special characters like spaces, hyphens and apostrophes
- Names that contain consecutive, identical special characters (eg -- or -')
- Probably more that I haven't mentioned (please comment if you think of any, I do a lot of this kind of validation and would be keen for other peoples opinions)

**Note:** *By special characters I mean 'pseudo-alphanumeric' symbols such as hyphens, spaces, apostrophes - things that are allowed in names but are not alphanumeric.*

My suggestion would be to run a separate regex for each condition you want to test for and accept the name only if all conditions pass. Doing it separately also allows you a greater ability to determine what exactly caused the name entered to be invalid.

I have about 15,000 users of the things I build using similarly restrictive validation and I have never had a problem with this method.

**EDIT:** It is obvious that my approach to this problem may exclude people, who have numbers or symbols in their name. The more conditions you impose the more of these people you will inconvenience.

---

## PLEASE DISREGARD EVERYTHING ABOVE THIS LINE

Going into this question it was my honest and humble opinion that it was sensible to to be validating 'junk' from names and as such I feel it would be dishonest of me to erase my original answer.

I would still recommend it as a technique for validating more uniform input with better defined standards like dates, times, local telephone numbers.

Instead I want to say that having debated in the comments and read other answers, I too have come to the conclusion that you should not impose any conditions on names.

As long as you are sanitizing your input before it goes into the database anything goes, its not really my business and I don't even know why I care.

***Now if you will excuse me I have some code to fix...***

Comment: Jennifer 8 can go **** her self and her parents can too. The problem is if you allow jeniffer to have an 8 in her name, you have to allow every  body to have an 8 in their name unless... `if name := 'jenifer': /*allow numbers*/` :P

Comment: Well, you *do* have to allow everybody to have an 8 in their name, or any other number. You have to allow *anybody* to have ***anything*** in their name, because you don't get to make up the rules on what an "acceptable" name is.

Comment: And your "simple facts that hold true for any name" are not facts. Did you read the link to kalzumeus that @Alnitak provided?

Comment: I will concede that the more validation conditions you impose, the more special snowflakes you lock out. :P. None the less if you want to validate names I suggest using a method of black listing conditions rather than white listing conditions. At the end of the day people with ludicrous names are probably no strangers to rejection, hassle and not being taken seriously

Comment: I like your edit, and kudos for leaving it as a lesson! (+1) I have a completely normal name but get annoyed enough at all the sites that reject my *actual* email address as "invalid". Clearly it's valid, it's my (working) email address (which contains a '+' in it)